# Understanding input and labels in word2vec (TensorFlow)

Tags: arrays, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I am trying to properly understand the `batch_input` and `batch_labels` from the tensorflow ["Vector Representations of Words"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec) tutorial.

For instance, my data

```
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 251 371 371 1685 ...
```

... starts with

```
skip_window = 2 # How many words to consider left and right.
num_skips = 1 # How many times to reuse an input to generate a label.
```

Then the generated input array is:

```
bach_input = 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 251 371 ....
```

This makes sense, starts from after 2 (= window size) and then continuous. The labels:

```
batch_labels = 1 1 1 1 1 1 251 1 1685 371 589 ...
```

I don't understand these labels very well. There are supposed to be 4 labels for each input right (window size 2, on each side). But the `batch_label` variable is the same length.

From the tensorflow tutorial:

> The skip-gram model takes two inputs. One is a batch full of integers
>   representing the source context words, the other is for the target
>   words.

As per the tutorial, I have declared the two variables as:

```
  batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
  labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
```

How should I interpret the `batch_labels`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are supposed to be 4 labels for each input right (window size 2, on each side). But the batch_label variable is the same length.

The key setting is **`num_skips = 1`**. This value defines the number of `(input, label)` tuples each word generates. See the examples with different `num_skips` below (my `data` sequence seems to be different from yours, sorry about that).

### Example #1 - `num_skips=4`

```py
batch, labels = generate_batch(batch_size=8, num_skips=4, skip_window=2)
```

It generates 4 labels for each word, i.e. uses the whole context; since `batch_size=8` only 2 words are processed in this batch (*12* and *6*), the rest will go into the next batch:

```py
data = [5239, 3084, 12, 6, 195, 2, 3137, 46, 59, 156, 128, 742, 477, 10572, ...]
batch = [12 12 12 12  6  6  6  6]
labels = [[6 3084 5239 195 195 3084 12 2]]
```

### Example #2 - `num_skips=2`

```py
batch, labels = generate_batch(batch_size=8, num_skips=2, skip_window=2)
```

Here you would expect each word appear twice in the `batch` sequence; the 2 labels are randomly sampled from 4 possible words:

```py
data = [5239, 3084, 12, 6, 195, 2, 3137, 46, 59, 156, 128, 742, 477, 10572, ...]
batch = [ 12  12   6   6 195 195   2   2]
labels = [[ 195 3084   12  195 3137   12   46  195]]
```

### Example #3 - `num_skips=1`

```py
batch, labels = generate_batch(batch_size=8, num_skips=1, skip_window=2)
```

Finally, this setting, same as yours, produces exactly one label per each word; each label is drawn randomly from the 4-word context:

```py
data = [5239, 3084, 12, 6, 195, 2, 3137, 46, 59, 156, 128, 742, 477, 10572, ...]
batch = [  12    6  195    2 3137   46   59  156]
labels = [[  6  12  12 195  59 156  46  46]]
```

> How should I interpret the batch_labels?

Each label is the center word to be predicted from the context. But the generated data may take *not all* `(context, center)` tuples, depending on the settings of the generator.

Also note that the `train_labels` tensor is 1-dimensional. Skip-Gram trains the model to predict *any* context word from the given center word, not all 4 context words *at once*. This explains why all training pairs `(12, 6)`, `(12, 3084)`, `(12, 5239)` and `(12, 195)` are valid.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The order of the batch_labels is still not very clear to me. Also, skip gram takes as input the center word, and output (target/label) of the surrounding words? (ps don't think it matters, but my batch size was 128 in this example)

Comment: input/output pairs would look something like this for the last example right?: (input: 12; output: 5239, 3084, 6, 195); (input: 6; output: 3084, 12, 195, 2),...

Comment: The order is random - see this line in the generator `words_to_use = random.sample(context_words, num_skips)`. Also SG predicts the context from the center words.

Comment: Oh, random.. How would I be able to read an input/output pair from the batch and labels though? Are the inputs stored in batch and the outputs in labels? Is there any way to extract one of the input/output pairs, given your last example?

Comment: Not exactly. First, you're going sequentially, while the tutorial generator does random sampling. Secondly, you're taking `num_skips=4`. This is example #1 - there're indeed four of *12* and four of *6*. Also the output is one 1D, not 4D. So 4 examples go to the batch.

Comment: Thanks, I am understanding the random sampling (now num_skips makes sense). Not entirely clear on where the output.input is yet as per my previous comment.

Comment: I think your understanding is that each center words predicts the whole context **at once**. That's not how it works. Instead, SG trains the model to predict **any word** in the context. This way you are free to generate several labels for an input. And there're all correct! The output is thus just 1D, just like the input.

Comment: Ooooh, that wasn't clear to me. Thanks! So that also means that, for instance, a window size of 2 doesn't make much sense without a num_skip of at least 4.

Comment: It makes some sense, but in this case the generator clearly doesn't explore the whole input space: some (input,label) pairs are in the text, but the model will see only the part of it.

Comment: I understand yeah.

Comment: Btw, it seems like the classical image of representing skipgram doesn't really apply here, as I am expecting 1 output node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2YeO.png

Comment: As a last clarification, would you say that i.stack.imgur.com/O2YeO.png  doesn't apply here? of just that the output nodes are the number of times it is sampled? It seems to me like there should be only 1 output node.

Comment: Maybe this is a bit late but... May I ask why the label is a transposed vector? Thanks!