# Skip gram in word2vec - what is the number of outputs

Tags: word2vec

The following images are often represented to describe the word2vec model with skip-gram:

[image]

However, after reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302947/understanding-input-and-labels-in-word2vec-tensorflow) on stackoverflow, it seems that word2vec actually take 1 word and input and 1 word as output. The output word is randomly samples from the window. (And this is performed X number of times to generate X input/output pairs.)

It seems to me then that the above image is not correctly describing the network. My question is: is the 1 input/1 output standard (the Tensorflow word2vec tutorial takes this approach and calls it skip-gram) or do some networks actually take the structure of the above image?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great diagram.

In CBOW, those converging arrows are an averaging that happens all-at-once, to create one single 'training example' (desired prediction) that is (average(context1, context2, ..., contextN) -> target-word). (In practice averaging is more common than the 'SUM' shown in the diagram.)

In Skip-Gram, those diverging arrows are multiple training examples (desired predictions) made one-after-the-other.

And in both diagrams, while they look a bit like neural-net node-architectures, the actual hidden-layer and internal-connection weights are just implied inside the middle-column-to-right-column arrows.

Skip-gram is always 1 "input" context word used to predict 1 nearby (within the effective 'window') "output" target word.

Implementations tend to iterate through the whole effective window, so every (context -> target) pair gets used as a training-example. And in practice, it doesn't matter if you consider the central word the target-word and each word around it to be context-words, or the central word the context-word and each word around it to be target-words – both methods result in the exact same set of (word -> word) pairs being trained, just in a slightly different iteration order. (I believe the original Word2Vec paper described it one way, but then Google's released code did it the other way for reasons of slightly-better cache efficiency.)

In fact the effective window, for each central word considered, is chosen to be some random number from 1 to the configured maximum `window` value. This turns out to be a cheap way of essentially weighting nearer-words more: the immediate neighbors are always part of training-pairs, further words only sometimes. That is, pairs are *not* randomly sampled from the whole window - it's just a random window size. (There's another down-sampling where the most-frequent words will be randomly dropped so as not to overtrain them at the expense of less-frequent words, but that's a totally separate process not reflected in the above.)

In CBOW, instead of up-to 2*window input-output pairs of the (context-word -> target-word) form, there's a single input-output pair of (context-words-average -> target-word). (In CBOW, a loop creates the average value for a single N:1 training-example for one central word, and then splits the backpropagated error across all contributing words. In skip-gram, a loop creates multiple alternate 1:1 training-examples for one central word.)